# How do I show this firebase database structure on a jTable?

Tags: java, firebase, swing, firebase-realtime-database, jtable

Im not sure how I can show this data on my jTable. Can anyone suggest me on how I can retrieve this firebase database structure. I dont have problem in jTable, its just how to access the nodes. Sorry for my bad english, hope you get my point.

[Firebase Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2KyD.png)

This is my code:

```
DatabaseReference getSubj = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Teachers").
            child(LoginFrame.sUserKey).child("Subjects");
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tblSubjects.getModel();
    Object[] row = new Object[4];

    getSubj.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot ds) {
            model.setNumRows(0);
            listSubjID.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : ds.getChildren()) {
                Subject subject = new Subject();

                subject.setSubjCode(dataSnapshot.child("Subject Details").child("subjCode").getValue().toString());
                subject.setSubjTitle(dataSnapshot.child("Subject Details").child("subjTitle").getValue().toString());
                subject.setUnits(dataSnapshot.child("Subject Details").child("units").getValue().toString());
                subject.setSection(dataSnapshot.child("Subject Details").child("section").getValue().toString());

                listSubjID.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());

                row[0] = subject.getSubjCode();
                row[1] = subject.getSubjTitle();
                row[2] = subject.getUnits();
                row[3] = subject.getSection();

                model.addRow(row);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError de) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not updating the JTable after retrieving the data from firebase.

Try this:

table1.setModel(model);

ps. table1 is the JTable field name in your design form